# How to automate cutting the part with audio on a certain track out?

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, automation

How to automate cutting the bits with audio on a certain track out?

So here is the deal.
We live recording radio shows with video.
But we do not have permission to use the music played. So we need to manually rremove it from the video.

There is a single audiotrack for the music playing.
Video Track
Audio track 1 - Everything.
Audio track 2 - Microphones
Audio track 3 - Music
Audio track 4 - Sound bits.

So i have to remove all the pars where there is sound on audio track 3 :)

So my question is - is there anyway to automate this? Either full automatic (FFMEPG)
or in Premiere Pro- A way to select bits on a audio track where volume is over X? and also select all other tracks.

Help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZeO0IQaJ-A) did essentially the opposite of what you're trying to do. However, he posted the source-code [here.](https://github.com/DevonCrawford/Video-Editing-Automation) So with a little bit of IT-finesse, you should be able to reverse the program's understanding of what to edit out - meaning that the code shouldn't say (in a very simplified, theoretical syntax):

```
if track5dB < 5dB:
{
cutThisOut();
}
```

but instead:

```
if track5dB > 0
{
cutThisOut();
}
```

Now, I haven't personally checked out the code in detail, so I cannot 100% vouch for it to work, but it might just be worth a try.

Comment: Amazing. I have watched the video. But did not see that he posted the source. I'll try it out.